How to remove unnecessary logs in FastAPI?
A few days ago, I integrated GoAccess with my FastAPI access.log file to analyze the request traffic in real time.
It works good so far.
I tried to use access.log file to record only clients' requests.
Additionally, I had to match the logging format defined by GoAccess to analyze the traffic.
logging.basicConfig(filename='access.log', level=logging.INFO, 
                    format='%(message)s')

@app.middleware("http")
async def log_requests(request: Request, call_next):
    start_time = datetime.now()
    response = await call_next(request)
    process_time = (datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds()
    
    log = f'{request.client.host} - - [{start_time.strftime("%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z")}] "{request.method} {request.url.path} HTTP/{request.scope["http_version"]}" {response.status_code} {response.headers.get("content-length", "-")} "{request.headers.get("referer", "-")}" "{request.headers.get("user-agent", "-")}"'
    
    logging.info(log)
    
    return response

But when interior requests to other third-parties are triggered, they are also recorded like this:
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2024:19:28:49 ] "GET /traffic-report HTTP/1.1" 200 710424 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
HTTP Request: POST http://to_other_service/hook/token/equity "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"

I triggered interior requests using Httpx package.
Please let me know why it is recorded automatically and how to fix this.
Thank you very much.
I tried to find any code snippets that is slipped into the access.log record, but I didn't find it.
The expected result should be like this:

Only requests from customers should be recorded in access.log.
Any requests triggered in the server itself shouldn't be recorded automatically.

127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2024:19:28:38 ] "GET /traffic-report HTTP/1.1" 200 710424 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Dec/2024:19:28:49 ] "GET /traffic-report HTTP/1.1" 200 710424 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"


This might help.

Have a look at this too.

"But when interior requests to other third-parties are triggered..." Where are these in your question? Please see [ask] and provide a [mre] that people can easily understand and use to reproduce the issue, not just parts of your code that provide little information and help to us
